# Какой потомок вызвал статический метод родителя? или миссия невыполнима?

Tags: c#, ооп

Я получил тестовое задание во время собеседования на должность *C#* программиста, но так и не смог его решить, т.к. не понял что именно требуется.

Пишу это, т.к. хочу совершенствоваться, заканчивать все начатые дела, понимать и знать то что до этого не понимал или не знал по мере возможности.

Со словами "вот лёгенькое тестовое задание" интервьюер отправил мне email. Цитирую постановку:

> Классы `А` и `В` не включают реализации свойств, полей и методов, не атрибутированы и являются наследниками общего предка `С`
>
> 1) не создавая экземпляров описанных классов, реализовать в классе `C` статический метод с сигнатурой `public static string GetName()`, для которого истинно `A.GetName() == "A" && B.GetName() == "B"`
>
> 2) реализовать единый счетчик количества экземпляров всех наследников класса `С` с сигнатурой поля `public static int Count` в классе, не лежащем вне линии наследования

Я уточнил у интервьюера, что имеется в виду под константами `"A"` и `"B"` - он ответил, что это именно имена классов. Т.е. метод `GetName()` должен возвращать имя класса потомка.

В процессе тщетных попыток реализовать в точности как описано в задании и яростного гугления был найден материал со *stackoverflow*:

- [How to get the class Type in a base class static method in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669166/how-to-get-the-class-type-in-a-base-class-static-method-in-net)
- [Get inherited caller type name in base static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736392/get-inherited-caller-type-name-in-base-static-class)

Где, на сколько я понял, утверждается, что получить имя класса потомка из статического метода невозможно без хаков.

Я прикидывал ещё несколько вариантов (например, создание нового класса, который не описан в задании), но все они связаны с попытками обхода условий, что не вяжется со словами интервьюера о том, что есть конкретное решение, думаю оно должно быть честное и простое, раз он так вначале утверждал.

У меня получилось сделать только это, но я знаю, что это неверно, т.к. метод `GetName` не статический и создаются экземпляры класса:

1.

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( new A().GetName() == "A" && new B().GetName() == "B" );
        }
    }
    class C {
        public string GetName() {
            return this.GetType().Name;
        }
    }
    class A : C{}
    class B : C{}
}
```

2.

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {                
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new A();
            var b = new B();
            var c = new C();
        }
    }
    public class C {
        public static int Count;

        public C () {

            if ( this is A
               || this is B )
                Count++;
            Console.WriteLine ( "Count is: " + Count );
        }
    }
    public class A : C{}
    public class B : C{}
}
```

Ответ интервьювера:

> А:добрый день, я вижу, однако вынужден огорчить, задача имеет конкретное решение
>
> Б:Т.е. ни один из двух пунктов неверный?
>
> А:второй зависит от первого
>
> А:и соотвественно, первый не верен, так как создавать экземпляров нельзя

Пожалуйста, помогите мне решить эту задачу. Мне кажется, что в самой постановке есть противоречия, тем более в ней используется двойное отрицание, что трудно для понимания.

Обновлено:
Коллеги, благодаря вашим ответам, пояснениям и замечаниям мне всё-таки удалось решить задачу так: создал ещё один класс C, который сделал базовым для всех и установил в нём счётчик. Новый класс обеспечил выполнение условия "А и B являются наследниками общего предка С".

```
using System;
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main ( string[] args )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( A.GetName() == "A" 
                               && B.GetName() == "B" );

            new A (); // 1 
            new B (); // 2
            new C (); // 3
            new A (); // 4
            new B (); // 5
        }
    }

    class C {
        public static int Count;
    }

    class C < T > : C where T: C < T > {

        public C () { 

            if ( this is A
               || this is B )

                Count++;
            Console.WriteLine ( "Count is:" + Count );
        }

        public static string GetName(){
            return typeof ( T ).Name;
        }
    }

    class A : C < A > { }
    class B : C < B > { }

}
```

Благодаря ответам и замечаниям иностранных коллег, этот код я дополнил соответствующими модификаторами: базовый класс `C` и `C < T >` пометил модификатором `abstract`, определяющим данные классы как базовые, а поле `Count` дополнил геттером и сеттером ( с модификатором доступа `protected` ), для ограничения доступа к переменной. Так же конструктор базового класса `C` помечен модификатором доступа `protected`. Допиленный вариант решения:

```
using System;
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main ( string[] args )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( A.GetName() == "A" 
                               && B.GetName() == "B" );

            new A (); 
            new B ();
        }
    }

    abstract class C {
        public static int Count { get; protected set;}
    }

    abstract class C < T > : C where T: C < T > {

        protected C () { 

            if ( this is A
               || this is B )

                Count++;
            Console.WriteLine ( "Count is:" + Count );
        }

        public static string GetName(){
            return typeof ( T ).Name;
        }
    }

    class A : C < A > { }
    class B : C < B > { }

}
```

Спасибо всем, кто участвовал в решении этой головоломки! Вы потрясающие люди)

Comment: Зовите <del>Вия</del> VlaD'а :)

Comment: эти два пункта должны быть в одних и тех же классах реализованы, или для каждого пункта отдельное решение?

Comment: @tutankhamun, таки VladD'a. :) Я бы сказал, что первая часть задачи нерешаема. По второй - согласен с идеей автора: в конструкторе `C` увеличивать статический счетчик, если тип не `C`.

Comment: Это ничего, что в `общего предка С` русская `С`, а в `реализовать в классе C` - латинская? Или это разные классы?

Comment: @alexolut Глаз-алмаз. Я думаю, что это просто опечатка.

Comment: @hwak если это формальное ТЗ в электронной форме, то можно использовать в своих целях:)

Comment: А можно взять Delphi.NET и воспользоваться его фичами с метаклассами?))))

Comment: Отправьте интервьюеру ссылку на эту тему с просьбой дать ответ, или больше не предлагать на собеседованиях вопросы, не имеющие решений.

Comment: "Заканчивать начатые дела" - плохая привычка, подумайте, что есть трактор, не обязательно поле перекапывать лопатой, даже если вдруг уже начали.

Comment: Лучше "решение" вынести как ответ. Хотя условие `реализовать в классе C статический метод` тем не менее не выполнено.

Comment: @alexolut, ну это смотря как считать :) Просто тут **два** класса `C` :-)

Comment: @Grundy значит моя догадка про русскую и латинскую буквы была не безосновательна :) Классы действительно разные.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Как сказано в ответах по ссылке. В простейшем случае

```
class C { public static string GetName() => ... }
class A : C {}
class B : C {}
```

В методе `GetName` нельзя узнать тип наследника, просто потому, что статические методы не переопределяются, и в IL будет стоять не

```
call A.GetName
```

а

```
call C.GetName
```

---

Так как ограничений на класс `C` нет, его можно сделать `generic` классом. Наследники будут специфицировать generic параметр собой и в этом случае базовый класс может выглядеть так:

```
class C<T>
{
    public static string GetName() => typeof(T).Name;
}
```

Наследники:

```
class A : C<A> { }
class B : C<B> { }
```

В этом случае: `A.GetName()` вернет "A", `B.GetName()` вернет "B",

Comment: Если это правильный ответ (а он похож на то, что могли спросить), то я бы не пошел туда работать. Это ж зачем такое могло понадобиться...

Comment: @Grundy Огромное спасибо за ваш ответ. Это действительно то решение, которое ожидал интервьювер. Перед тем как вы ответили, интервьювер дал мне подсказку: "В качестве подсказки, посмотрите шаблон проектирования CRTP". И из статей в открытых источниках я пришёл к аналогичному решению ещё до того, как ознакомился с тем что отправили вы. Ещё раз большое вам спасибо, вы сделали этот сайт ещё прекраснее!

Comment: @Monk, как в комментарии выше написано _шаблон проектирования CRTP_ :-)

Comment: @hwak, в любом случае, мне кажется с формулировкой вопроса, что-то не то :)

Comment: @Grundy у паттерна совсем не такие цели, чтобы по вопросу понять о чём речь. То, что вы его узнали в вопросе - для меня чудо =)

Comment: @Monk, не узнал :-) я даже название вспомнить не смог :):):) просто по другому никак не получалось

Comment: @Monk понадобиться это могло во многих местах - но вот правильным ответом не является. Поэтому если такое интервьюверы считают правильным ответом - я бы тоже не пошел туды работать.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Поясните, пожалуйста, почему это не правильный ответ? Я хочу знать как нужно было бы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov статический метод, который возвращает разные результаты в зависимости от того, откуда он вызван - это ОПАСНЫЙ код. Я не знаю, где такое может понадобиться.

Comment: @hwak дело в том, что C<A> и C<B> - это разные классы. То есть не выполняется условие "у A и B есть общий предок".

Comment: @Monk в чем опасность, если это поведение документировано?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Точно подмечено. Отсюда вывод - решения у обоих задач нет (т.к. вторая связана с первой)?

Comment: @PavelMayorov пример с толку сбил. Это же какой нибудь вполне привычный метод Create у репозитория. Возвращает всегда ожидаемый мной тип просто, а не строку, общий тип на все случаи жизни.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, на самом деле `C<T>` можно унаследовать от `C` и общий предок будет :)

Comment: @Grundy но статический метод то там не объявишь? =)

Comment: @hwak, лучше добавь свой ответ с пояснением решения

Answer (score 15):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081687/5232946) Jon Skeet пишет, что в рантайме узнать тип класса-наследника через статический метод базового класса невозможно, поскольку в процессе компиляции в *IL* (надеюсь я правильно выражаюсь) пишется тип класса, который его реализует, т.е. о наследнике какая-либо информация попросту отсутствует.

Answer (score 11):

В рамках наркомании, вот этот пример пройдет проверочный кейс:

```
  public class C
  {
    private static bool isAreturned = false;

    public static string GetName()
    {
      isAreturned = !isAreturned;
      return isAreturned ? "A" : "B";
    }
  }

  public class A : C { }
  public class B : C { }
```

Comment: эм... только в том случае, если строгий порядок вызовы функции... но, да :) Формально тест пройдет :)

Comment: @Grundy именно, на это и расчет. Правда, я всё равно не смог придумать, как будут связаны 1 и 2 вопросы в такой интерпретации.

Comment: Что есть "проверочный кейс"?

Comment: @alexolut в данном случае - ситуация при которой истинно выражение A.GetName() == "A" && B.GetName() == "B"

Comment: Истинность этого выражения будет зависеть от истории вызовов `GetName`, поэтому нельзя говорить, что тест пройден.

Comment: @alexolut по коду же очевидно, как оно работает. Сам запрос точно обработает, любые другие проверки - конечно же нет.

Comment: Вот [пример](http://ideone.com/8X27u4), где запрос возвращает `False`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48733/discussion-between-monk-and-alexolut).

Answer (score 0):

На первый вопрос отправил бы такой код, потом бы мог поспорить какое из условий задания я не выполнил!

```
  public class D
{
    private string i = string.Empty;
        public D() { val = i; }
        public string val;

        public static bool flag = false;
        public static implicit operator string(D a)
        {
            if (!flag)
            {
                flag = true;
                return "A";
            }
            return "B";
        }



}
public class C :D
{
    public static bool Istina()
    {
        return A.GetName() == "A" && B.GetName() == "B";
    }
    public static string GetName()
    {
        return new D();
    }
}
public class A : C
{

}

public class B : C
{

}
```

Comment: Потом увидел у Monk, намного проще можно было реализовать)

Comment: например: _не создавая экземпляров описанных классов_, `new C` создает экземпляр описанного класса :)

Comment: @Grundy из задачи понял что речь о классах A и B

Comment: Тут да, очередной спорный момент :)

Comment: @Grundy убрал противоречия с условием)