# Как получить название класса в котором вызываем статический метод, который он наследует от другого родительского класса

Tags: c#

```
Tickers.All();

class Tickers : Eloquent
{

}

class Eloquent
{
    public static void All()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Класс из которого вызывали меня");
    }
}
```

Хочу в классе Eloquent получить название класса Tickers.

Подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что это возможно, потому что на самом деле будет вызван метод класса Eloquent: [ссылка](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjlACxwCyAFAJQlkXsAqAlgMYDWAUwBOAZwB0AQQA2U5mnTsAvhmXoMUfN37CRcEHACiUgPYBHAK4CAdgBcMpNelXr8Rs5dv225bAkQA2BFppWSZvVgV2CiQATgYAIkAsEEBuEEAGEEBBEHS4QA4QQHYQOEAuEEA+EEAhECLAARAiwGYQIrhAJhBAaRBchrrU5Oy4QB4QQFYQQF4QQHkQeKZ5JRUgA)

Comment: Максимум вы можете хранить у себя статическую строку с именем класса и возвращает её, ну или стат поля обжект и в стат конструкторе присваивать ему экземпляр класса, но это такое себе решение. По другому увы не выйдет. Но обычно если что-то нельзя сделать, то скорее всего что-то пошло не так ещё до того, как это понадобилось)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем Вам это надо.

Comment: Делаю класс который будет содержать в себе методы для работы с бд и от которого будут наследоваться классы одноименные с названием таблиц в базе. К примеру я вызываю в в классе Tickers статический метод All который находится в классе Eloquent. Метод смотрит название класса из которого его вызвали и использует это имя для работы с базой.

Comment: В таких случаях следует использовать не статические, а обычные методы. А иногда - даже виртуальные.

Comment: это можно, только если пройтись по всем типам сборки и проверить на parenttype==Eloquent. По другому никак: родительский класс ничего не знает о дочерних и не может узнать

Comment: По большому счету вам нужно этот метод реализовать в дочерних классах через override, а в родительском как виртуальный, как Игорь намекнул выше. И вы получите как раз тот самый метод, который вы хотите, имхо, с меньшими затратами... В принципе, наверное, даже можно, может быть, его и не переопределять в дочерних. А сделать в родителе this GetType. Или если Статик, то methodbase.getcurrentmethod().declaredtype или что-то в таком духе. Но надо пробовать. Я не уверен

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какой потомок вызвал статический метод родителя? или миссия невыполнима?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592600/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Статические методы** привязаны к определенному типу и **не наследуются**. В вашем случае `Tickers.All()` на самом деле скомпилится в `Eloquent.All()`, поэтому в рантайме не будет даже упоминания о `Tickers`.

Чтобы реализовать вашу задумку, нужно немного подшаманить:

**Вариант 1**

```
class Tickers : Eloquent
{
    public static new void All() => Eloquent.All();
}

class Eloquent
{
    public static void All()
    {
        var stacktrace = new StackTrace();
        var prevframe = stacktrace.GetFrame(1);
        var method = prevframe.GetMethod();

        Console.WriteLine($"Вызывающий класс: {method.ReflectedType.Name}");
    }
}
```

Либо, как прокомментировал *@Grundy*, посмотреть [еще один способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592600/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0). Если коротко, то:

**Вариант 2**

```
class Tickers : Eloquent<Tickers>
{
}

class Eloquent<T> where T: Eloquent<T>
{
    public static void All()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Вызывающий класс: {typeof(T).Name}");
    }
}
```